# Delaying Streams in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, stream

I'm attempting to make 90-second delay bot in node.js for Mumble (an audio chat program). I'm using [node-mumble](https://github.com/Rantanen/node-mumble) and have been looking at [node-delayed-stream](https://github.com/felixge/node-delayed-stream).

So I tried using:

```
mumble.connect( 'localhost:5432', function( error, connection ) {
    if( error ) { throw new Error( error ); }

    connection.authenticate('loopback-' + unique);
    connection.on( 'initialized', function() {
        var delayed = DelayedStream.create(connection.outputStream());
        setTimeout(function() {
            delayed.pipe(connection.inputStream());
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

However, the outputStream (audio flowing to bot) will pause if no one is talking, which means that the inputStream (input audio to mumble server) has time to catch up and will eventually be in sync again.

Here's an idea of the effect I want but with the worst quality imaginable:

```
mumble.connect( 'localhost:5432', function( error, connection ) {
    if( error ) { throw new Error( error ); }

    connection.authenticate('loopback-' + unique);
    connection.on( 'initialized', function() {
        connection.outputStream().on('data', function(d) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                connection.inputStream().write(d);
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
});
```

How do I always keep a smooth, X second delay on the stream?